# Is there a library for generating VECTOR QR Codes on a LAMP stack?

Tags: php, qr-code

Are there any libraries; proprietary or Open Source (but preferably Open Source) that can generate vector QR codes on a LAMP stack?

I would like to use it within a PHP web application.

Comment: Zint appears to be Windows

Comment: That's what I'm using now.  I want to switch to vector.

Comment: You can use vector in that library. You can render to an svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the library http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ which supports SVG.

```
<?php 

include('../lib/full/qrlib.php'); 

// SVG file format support 

$svgCode = QRcode::svg('PHP QR Code :)'); 

echo $svgCode;
```

Example http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/example_201_basic_svg.php

Comment: it's not working on my end   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method QRcode::svg() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php7\phpqrcode\test2.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php7\phpqrcode\test2.php on line 3

Comment: should check this: https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode
-It seem the http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ basic not include vector function.